# Graphicsmagick is taking more processing time on server

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, graphicsmagick, gm

I am using GraphicsMagick to colorize multiple layers of images and composing it to form single image and returning it.

On local it was taking around **30ms** to process single layer (1000 x 1000).

Following is the image.

[image]

Following is my colorization code:

```
var colorizeImage = function(imageName, hex, callback) {
  //Setting image path.
  var sourceImgSrc = getSourceImgSrc(imageName); //Source image path
  var convertedImgSrc = getConvertedImgSrc(imageName); // New image path
  var hslObj = getConvertedHSLFromHex(hex);
  var hue = hslObj.h;
  var saturation = hslObj.s; 
  var lightness = hslObj.l; 
  try{
      //Query  
        var modulateImg = "gm convert -resize 500 "+sourceImgSrc+" -modulate "+lightness+","+saturation+","+hue+" -limit memory 100KB "+convertedImgSrc; 

        exec(modulateImg, function(err) {
          if (err) {
            callback('', err);
          } 
          else{
            callback(convertedImgSrc);
          }

        });
  }
  catch(err){
    callback('', err);
  }
}
```

But, When I have hosted this to my server and performed load testing with only 50 concurrent users load. Performance for single layer gets degraded to around **250ms** for single layer.

**Following is my Server Config:**

**GraphicsMagick:** 1.3.26

**OS:** Window server 2012

**Processor:** Intel(R) Xeon(R) 2.40 GHz (2 Processors)

**RAM:** 128GB

Please help me to improve performance so that it can handle huge load easily.

Thanks.

Comment: It's hard to work out what is wrong with something we can't see! Please show your code and also provide a sample image.

Comment: Why are you limiting memory - which will force things to disk and slow everything down?

Comment: I have removed that but not much difference in performance.